# MS SQL update query on int column with an empty value

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My table has two columns - col1 (int, null) and col2 (int, null) which I want to be able update with an empty values or null statement.

My code looks like:

```
            $newkeylimit = $allkeylimits[$row['Group_ID']];
            if($newkeylimit == ''){ $newkeylimit = NULL ; }

            $newproflimit = $allproflimits[$row['Group_ID']];                               
            if($newproflimit == ''){ $newproflimit = NULL ; }

            $sql = "UPDATE ".$mssql_table_prefix."Groups SET Group_Name = '".$newgroupname."', col1 = '".$newkeylimit."', col2 = '".$newproflimit."' WHERE Group_ID = '".$row['Group_ID']."'";
            $result = mssql_query($sql)
                or die( "<strong>ERROR: Group update query failed</strong>" );
```

After code execution I'm getting 0 in each column where suppose to be an empty value or NULL. Default values for col1 and col2 are set to NULL.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: OK, I have changed code above to:     if(empty($newkeylimit) && empty($newproflimit)){
     $sqlup = "UPDATE ".$mssql_table_prefix."Groups SET Group_Name = '".$newgroupname."', col1 = null, col2 = null WHERE Group_ID = '".$row['Group_ID']."'";     
    }

    else {
    $sqlup = "UPDATE ".$mssql_table_prefix."Groups SET Group_Name = '".$newgroupname."', col1 = '".$newkeylimit."', col2 = '".$newproflimit."' WHERE Group_ID = '".$row['Group_ID']."'";    } and it works, somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a string instead of NULL to the server.  Get rid of the apostrophes (') for col1 and col2.

Comment: My code hasn't apostrophes (') for col1 and col2. Even switching if($newkeylimit == '') to if(empty($newkeylimit)) doesn't help

Comment: got it! I'm passing NULL as string anyway when passing variable with open/closed apostrophes. Thanks.

Comment: No clue who did that, but your answer is better then below one which is not correct because he is passing NULL as string as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set to 'NULL'. You set to NULL instead.
Try this.

```
        $newkeylimit = $allkeylimits[$row['Group_ID']];
        if($newkeylimit == "''"){ $newkeylimit = "NULL" ; }

        $newproflimit = $allproflimits[$row['Group_ID']];                               
        if($newproflimit == '""'){ $newproflimit = "NULL" ; }

        $sql = "UPDATE ".$mssql_table_prefix."Groups SET Group_Name = '".$newgroupname."',                col1 = ".$newkeylimit.", col2 = ".$newproflimit." WHERE Group_ID = '".$row['Group_ID']."'";
```

Comment: As mentioned below - code is passing NULL as string not int. Also IF statements are not valid for me (searching for double apostrophes or quotations)